# I'm unable to push a new route when using ShellRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router

I'm building a sleep analysis app using Flutter, and I just started using go_router to manage all my routes. I have what I'll describe as my main screen, which is 4 screens with a nested navigation bar. Some of theses routes have subroutes: let's sat that I have a /settings route (which is a part of my ShellRoute), there is also /settings/profile to manage the profile, /settings/password to change the password, and the list goes on.
However, I'm unable to `context.push('/settings/my_subroute')` as this doesn't work at all. `context.go` seems to be fine. I need to push the page in order to provide a back button. Here are my `router.dart` file:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/auth',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return const BottomNavBar();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          name: 'home',
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'sleep',
          path: '/sleep',
          builder: (context, state) => const SleepScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'dreams',
          path: '/dreams',
          builder: (context, state) => const DreamsScreen(),
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: 'add',
              builder: (context, state) => const AddDreamScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'settings',
          path: '/settings',
          builder: (context, state) => const SettingsMainScreen(),
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              name: 'profile',
              path: 'profile',
              builder: (context, state) => const SettingsProfileScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              name: 'email',
              path: 'email',
              builder: (context, state) => const SettingsEmailScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              name: 'password',
              path: 'password',
              builder: (context, state) => const SettingsPasswordScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

My main concern is some kind of context issue with the fact I used a ShellRoute before. Also, I think this might not be supported at all (and maybe even not the right way of doing what I'm trying to achieve). Is there a way to make `context.push` work in my case?

Comment: have you tried? pushNamed?

Comment: Yes, tried this as well but still no luck

Comment: related?: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140586